Is it possible to validate the Metamask personal_sign in the back end?
I am trying to understand the point of signing a personal message in the client. I guess this is usefull to confirm that the user is the owner of the address. But since this sign is done in the client we need a way to confirm in the backend that the message has been signed with the correct address. Is this possible with ethers.js?

I've implemented this.
What you can do is, in an API send user address to the backend and get a signature message from backend. Something like "Sign this message: <any random string>"
Then in frontend sign that message and you'll get back a signature, send that signature back to backend and verify. If signature is correct generate jwt.

This is an example in javascript and nodejs to solve this.
// Client javascript
const message = "My Message";
const address = '0x2e1fe3c3bf4c576d34c4048e5e7a8055b92a2e21';
const message_hex = `0x${Buffer.from(message, "utf8").toString("hex")}`;
const message_signed = await ethereum.request({
    method: "personal_sign",
    params: [message_hex, from],
})

// Server node.js
const { ethers } = require('ethers')
const address_returned = ethers.verifyMessage(message, message_signed)
console.log(address.toLowerCase()===address_returned.toLowerCase())

